# Где находится exe файл программы C# под Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Поставлена последняя версия VS Community 2019. Компилирую простенькую консольную программу.

Собственно, везде написано, что exe файл должен находиться в папке `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1`, или же в Release (в зависимости от режима).

Но как я не пытался (запуск приложения, сборка, стройка), исполняемого файла в данной папке нету. В этой папке только какие-то файлы с расширением `.pdb .json .dll`

И вообще его нигде нету. Программа то запускается в VS, но исполняемый файл куда-то запрятан. Вопрос: куда?

Comment: Или вы плохо искали, или компилируете не простенькую  консольную программу, а что-то ещё.

Comment: а если publish в папку сделать, там будет ваш exe?

Comment: У вас .NET Core проект?

Comment: разберитесь с таргетами

Comment: @АндрейNOP .Net Core 2.1 консольное приложение

Comment: @PavelMayorov, возникает ошибка System.InvalidOperationException: "Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined."

Answer (score -1):

Дело было в том, что я создавал консольное приложение для среды **.Net Core**.

Эта среда (как я понял) необходима для создания кроссплатформенных приложений, поэтому собственно файлы **.exe**  не создаются.

Чтобы создавались исполняемые файлы, необходимо использовать другую среду: **.Net Framework**

Comment: target runtime надо было указать win-x64 и был бы у вас исполнимый файл приложения

Comment: Для меня тоже сначала было шоком, что нет exe-файлов. Можно смотреть на это как на философию .net core. Скомпилить exe-файлы можно (они будут просто огромные) и под конкретную архитектуру (win-x64, linux-x64). а dll-файлы маленькие и запускаются через dotnet.exe. мне тоже больше нравится классическая .net архитектура. наверное адепты микрософта как то более точно это объяснят.

Comment: здесь описано, как сделать exe-файл (судя по количеству лайков, это беспокоит многих): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe

Comment: я обычно portable собираю :)

Comment: Вообще-то exe-файлы в .Net Core ещё как создаются.